# Is there a way to optimize multiple numpy.where functions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to optimize the following python code.

I have a dataframe that looks like this one

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
        "code": ["500","500","100","500","42", "100", "500"],
        "color": ["blue", "green", "red", "blue", "yellow", "red", "green"]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["new_column"] = ""


print(df)

  code   color new_column
0  500    blue           
1  500   green           
2  100     red           
3  500    blue           
4   42  yellow           
5  100     red           
6  500   green
```

The next step would be to populate the "new_colum" with a values which should be chosen according to the combination of values in the first two columns (e.g. if code = 500 and color = blue, new_colum = 1).

The (working) solution I have so far is the following

```
df["new_column"] = np.where((df["code"] == "500") & (df["color"] == "blue"), "1", df["new_column"])
df["new_column"] = np.where((df["code"] == "500") & (df["color"] == "green"), "2", df["new_column"])
df["new_column"] = np.where((df["code"] == "100") & (df["color"] == "red"), "3", df["new_column"])
df["new_column"] = np.where((df["code"] == "42") & (df["color"] == "yellow"), "4", df["new_column"])
```

which gives

```
  code   color new_column
0  500    blue          1
1  500   green          2
2  100     red          3
3  500    blue          1
4   42  yellow          4
5  100     red          3
6  500   green          2
```

my question is: is there a "more elegant" way to achieve the same result?
In this example I am using only four `np.where` functions but I have several combinations of values that should be cover with this methods, resulting in a "wall of text" that I hope to slim somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) is the way to chain multiple conditions, but in your case using a dictionary and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) is likely the best approach:

```
d = {('500', 'blue'): '1', ('500', 'green'): '2',
     ('100', 'red'): '3', ('42', 'yellow'): '4'}

cols = ['code', 'color']
df['new_column'] = df[cols].merge(pd.Series(d, name='X'), left_on=cols,
                                  right_index=True, how='left')['X']
```

Output:

```
  code   color new_column
0  500    blue          1
1  500   green          2
2  100     red          3
3  500    blue          1
4   42  yellow          4
5  100     red          3
6  500   green          2
```

Answer (score 2):

Yea,there is a more elegant way to achieve the same result

```
mapping = {
        ("500", "blue"): "1",
        ("500", "green"): "2",
        ("100", "red"): "3",
        ("42", "yellow"): "4"
    }
df["new_column"] = [mapping.get((code, color), "") for code, color in zip(df["code"], df["color"])]
```

Comment: Not sure if you tested it, but this is not going to work…

Comment: yeah, true i will update it